# Decompile .pyc in python 3.11 Fail: "Unsupported opcode: POP_JUMP_FORWARD_IF_FALSE"

Tags: python, decompiler, python-3.11

I have tried the tool of pycdc. The result is that it did' t work for python3.11.

```
# Source Generated with Decompyle++
# File: Demand_Change_Report.pyc (Python 3.11)

Unsupported opcode: POP_JUMP_FORWARD_IF_FALSE
import PySimpleGUI as sg
import pandas as pd
from icecream import ic
import shutil
import os
import datetime
import time
import openpyxl

def gui():
Unsupported opcode: KW_NAMES
    pass
# WARNING: Decompyle incomplete


def data_processed1(data_path, cqtr, nqtr):
Unsupported opcode: KW_NAMES
    pass
# WARNING: Decompyle incomplete


def main():
Error decompyling Demand_Change_Report.pyc: invalid vector subscript
```

And I tried the `uncompyle6` and `decompyle3`. They all failed. I asked the developer Rocket. He said they did not support python3.11. The error message is "`Unknown magical code 3495`".

If you have any tool can help me solve the question.

`uncompyle6` `decompyle3` `pycdc` and some websites

Comment: I have tried everything you can image, including pyjumpck, uncompyle6, decompyle3. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

> Unsupported opcode: POP_JUMP_FORWARD_IF_FALSE

That most likely means that this opcode is new in 3.11 and the decompiler doesn't support it yet.

As it always is with OSS, you can either add the support yourself or commission someone else to add it for you.